# C -Segmentation fault !

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, call

It seems at least weird to me... The program runs normally.But after I call the enter() function for the 4th time,there is a segmentation fault!I would appreciate any help.

With the following function enter() I wanna add user commands' datas to a list.

[Some part of the code is already posted on another question of me, but I think I should post it again...as it's a different problem I'm facing now.]

```
    /* struct for all the datas that user enters on file*/
typedef struct catalog    
{      char short_name[50];                    
       char surname[50];                       
       signed int amount;                      
       char description[1000];              
       struct catalog *next;
}catalog,*catalogPointer;   

catalogPointer current;
catalogPointer head = NULL; 

void enter(void)    //user command: i <name> <surname> <amount> <description>

{   
    int n,j=2,k=0;
    char temp[1500];
    char *short_name,*surname,*description;
    signed int amount;

    char* params = strchr(command,' ') + 1;  //strchr returns a pointer to the 1st space on the command.U want a pointer to the char right after that space.
    strcpy(temp, params);               //params is saved as temp.

    char *curToken = strtok(temp," ");      //strtok cuts 'temp' into strings between the spaces and saves them to 'curToken'
    printf("temp is:%s \n",temp);

    printf("\nWhat you entered for saving:\n");

    for (n = 0; curToken; ++n)          //until curToken ends:
    {   
        if (curToken)
        {   short_name = malloc(strlen(curToken) + 1);
            strncpy(short_name, curToken, sizeof (short_name));     
        }   
        printf("Short Name: %s \n",short_name);             

        curToken = strtok(NULL," ");                    
        if (curToken)
        {   surname = malloc(strlen(curToken) + 1);
            strncpy(surname, curToken,sizeof (surname));    }   
        printf("SurName: %s \n",surname);

        curToken = strtok(NULL," ");                    
        if (curToken)
        {   //int * amount= malloc(sizeof (signed int *));
            char *chk;                      
            amount = (int) strtol(curToken, &chk, 10);      

            if (!isspace(*chk) && *chk != 0)            
                    fprintf(stderr,"Warning: expected integer value for amount, received %s instead\n",curToken);
        }
        printf("Amount: %d \n",amount);
        curToken = strtok(NULL,"\0");                   
        if (curToken)
        {   description = malloc(strlen(curToken) + 1);
            strncpy(description, curToken, sizeof (description));   
        }
        printf("Description: %s \n",description);
        break;
    }

    if (findEntryExists(head, surname,short_name) != NULL)              //call function in order to see if entry exists already on the catalog
        printf("\nAn entry for <%s %s> is already in the catalog!\nNew entry not entered.\n",short_name,surname);
    else
    {
        printf("\nTry to entry <%s %s %d %s> in the catalog list!\n",short_name,surname,amount,description);
        newEntry(&head,short_name,surname,amount,description);  
        printf("\n**Entry done!**\n");
    }
    // Maintain the list in alphabetical order by surname.


}

catalogPointer findEntryExists (catalogPointer head, char num[],char first[])
{   catalogPointer p = head;
    while (p != NULL && strcmp(p->surname, num) != 0 && strcmp(p->short_name,first) != 0)      
    {   p = p->next;    }
    return p;
}

catalogPointer newEntry (catalog** headRef,char short_name[], char surname[], signed int amount, char description[])
{   
    catalogPointer newNode = (catalogPointer)malloc(sizeof(catalog));
    catalogPointer first;
    catalogPointer second;
    catalogPointer tmp;
    first=head;
    second=NULL;

    strcpy(newNode->short_name, short_name);        
    strcpy(newNode->surname, surname);
    newNode->amount=amount;
    strcpy(newNode->description, description);

    while (first!=NULL)                     
    {       if (strcmp(surname,first->surname)>0)
            second=first;
        else if (strcmp(surname,first->surname)==0)
            {
               if (strcmp(short_name,first->short_name)>0)
                   second=first;
            }
        first=first->next;
    }
    if (second==NULL)
    {       newNode->next=head;
        head=newNode;
    }
    else                             //SEGMENTATION APPEARS WHEN IT GETS HERE!
    {       tmp=second->next;
            newNode->next=tmp;
            first->next=newNode;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
SegFault appears only when it gets on the 'else' loop of InsertSort() function.
I observed that segmentation fault appears when i try to put on the list names that are after it. 
For example, if in the list exists:

[Name:b Surname:b   Amount:6    Description:b]
[Name:c Surname:c   Amount:5    Description:c]
[Name:d Surname:d   Amount:4    Description:d]
[Name:e Surname:e   Amount:3    Description:e]
[Name:g Surname:g   Amount:2    Description:g]
[Name:x Surname:x   Amount:1    Description:x]

and i put: " x z 77 gege" there is a segmentation
but if i put "x a 77 gege" it continues normally....

Comment: Please provide more details about the crash - specifically where in the code would be most helpful. Also please use this as a reference if it would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588853/the-community-driven-gdb-primer

Comment: where is command defined?  and also, you are leaking memory with no frees of the things you malloc.

Comment: Most probably you are writing past the end of an array somewhere ...

Comment: @Goz. That's right.But what is the fault on the code? I cant find it!

Comment: @SB. i free() everything. Problem is still there

Comment: If you have, or are using, a unit testing framework, I would totally add a test-case for this one, as it seems extremely sneaky.

Comment: @fbrereto I put some more details on the post about the crush. Hope to help a bit more

Comment: Could you show us how you call this code and where does the "command" come from?

Comment: It would also help to fix the code using advice from Samuel (sizeof gives size of the type which for c-string is just a pointer, not size of the string itself)

Comment: @MaR. I used what Smuel adviced me,but problem is still there. Command comes from console input from the user. I just didnt post that part of the code..'cause it's a rather big part of code

Comment: Well hard to tell. I applied Samuel's fix, compiled and it doesn't crash... (however if input is malformed, it crashed immediately ~ initialize short_name/surname/amount/description to NULL)

Comment: @MaR Just pay attention to my updated post. It doesnt crach all the times. Only when addition names are after the rest of the list it crashes!

Comment: @FILIaS: ah got it (one of the values wasn't added).

Comment: @Mar: It crashes when it gets to the last else of the last function I posted

Comment: @FILIaS: well yes, because "first" is NULL if any of the entries satisfies condition in the while loop.

Comment: @FILIaS: details posted as an "answer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't post into comment, so here it goes:

```
  while (first!=NULL)  {  //-> this loop can exit ONLY with 'first' being NULL
    if (strcmp(surname,first->surname)>0)
      second=first;
    else if (strcmp(surname,first->surname)==0)  {
      if (strcmp(short_name,first->short_name)>0)
        second=first;
    }
    first=first->next;
  } 
  if (second==NULL) {       
    newNode->next=head;
    head=newNode;
  }
  else { 
    tmp=second->next;
    newNode->next=tmp;
    first->next=newNode; // first used (but it's NULL!)
  }
```

In other words, your program will crash if it finds any entry that satisfy conditions inside the loop and set 'second'. (This triggers intended addition "inside" the list).

Ok ~ no time to wait for answer :o), in a case you want to enter "after" the 'second' change code to this:

```
  if (second==NULL) {       
    newNode->next=head;
    head=newNode;
  }
  else { 
    newNode->next=second->next;
    second->next=newNode; 
  }
```

explanation (S is 'second', N a 'newNode', A B just some exisiting entries in the list):

```
initial:
       N

  A -> S -> B

first assignment:
       N ---\
            |
            v
  A -> S -> B

second assignment:

       N ---\
       ^    |
       |    v
  A -> S    B

and thus:
  A-> S -> N -> B
```

Comment: Now the question is - how do you want to insert new entry in such case? Guessing after the 'second'?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what's causing the bug, but I did see this bad pattern:

```
char *short_name;
short_name = malloc(strlen(curToken) + 1);
strncpy(short_name, curToken, sizeof (short_name));
```

`sizeof(short_name)` will be always the same thing (usually 4 for 32 bit platforms and 8 for 64 bit platforms) so is not the correct value to use here.  You should be doing:

```
strncpy(short_name, curToken, strlen(curToken) + 1);
```

Comment: Since the segfault happens when trying to copy a string which was "initialized" in this way, this is likely the problem.  I would think that the printf's would show this...

Comment: @R Samuel Klatchko. Problem remains. Please see the updated post

Comment: @everybody SegFault comes when i add elements that are after those that they're alreasy on the list! So i think that the error is after enter() function

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find problems like this.

Comment: @twk: im sorry i have no idea what it is

Comment: @FILIaS Added a link to the suite @twk was referring to.

Comment: Thanx both of u,but as a beginner I dont know how to use it

Comment: What platform are you using?  Linux, mac, windows?

Comment: Also, and I mean this in the best possible way, but as a beginner part of job is learning how to use new tools.  Think of it as an investment.  It has a cost now, but it will pay off for the rest of your career.

Comment: @twk I'm using Linux.Thanx for the advice! I will keep it on mind!

Comment: okay, all you have to do is install valgrind, then (if the name of your executable is foo) run: valgrind ./foo    It will tell you where you are first corrupting the memory, which might not be where you first crash.

Comment: are you using a command line?  How are you running the program that is crashing right now?

Comment: Valgrind is immensely useful, just not in this case. There is no memory corrupted, unless it happens outside this piece of code or entries are too large to fit into catalog's fixed size entries. There is high probability of leaks though :o)

Comment: @FILLias -- yes, the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Falling out of your while loop requires first to be null.  In the else statement you attempt to access first.

Comment: So i need to initialise first with null? But what happens then on the other cases?

Comment: You could check to see if first->next is null, in cases when it is, don't assign first to first->next, simply break out of while loop.  Although based on other comments and the general code, it would seem that your intent is to break out of the loop when either second != NULL or first == NULL.  Regardless you will want to rework the code in the final else.